# 2 cells in one column in asp.net html

Tags: html, asp.net

Good day all, I want to make a data view using HTML table format in asp.net where it should look like this,

```
[USER_CODE]    [LAST_PRICE]
[CHANGE]
```

But in my website, everything is coming in a line. Here is my code,

```
@foreach (var item in Model.userstats)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.USER_CODE )</a></td>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LAST_PRICE)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CHANGE)
                </td>                    
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        }
```

How can I make the CHANGE cell go down under USER_CODE cell? I googled a lot but haven't find a solution that fits my purpose. Any help would be great. Tnx.

Comment: My suggestion: if you add borders to your table (temporarily), it will help you to see where things are going wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities for that:

1. Move [CHANGE] into the same `<td>` as [USER_CODE] separated with a `<br />`, which will forcibly expand the cell into a new line and show it below. To ensure [LAST_PRICE] remains on the very top part of the cell, use `<td valign="top">`, otherwise it will be vertically centered (default cell alignment).
2. Create a new row just for the [CHANGE] value and add `colspan="2"` to that `<td>` in order to make the second row cell expand horizontally below [LAST_PRICE], OR add an empty `<td>` to fill the empty space just below [LAST_PRICE].

Comment: Everything comes down after <br /> except for the 1st entry.